# stacking multiple `find -execute` invocations

Tags: find, xargs

i love `find -execute` but sometimes i would like to do more complex operations like running `find -execute` in all matching folders.

(e.g. run a script on all header files in a subdirectory tree for all base directories that were created after some date).

This can be accomplished with piping the output of one find into the next, like so:

```bsh
find . -type d -newermt 2021-01-01 -name "src" -print0 \
| xargs0 -IDIR find DIR -type f -name "*.h" -exec sed -e 's|Copyright|©|g' -i {} ";"
```

However, it would be possible to call one `find -execute` from another.

Somdething like this:

```bsh
find . -type d -newermt 2021-01-01 -name "src" -exec \
   find {}¹ -type f -name "*.h" -exec \
       sed -e 's|Copyright|©|g' -i {}² \
       +² \
   +¹
```

The obvious problem is to associate the placeholder (`{}`) and the expansion specifier (`+`, resp `;`) with the correct `find`.
In my code above i used the `¹` to indicate association with the 1st `find` and `²` for the 2nd instance.

So my question is: is it possible to call one `find` from another (multiple layers) or must i use `xargs` for stacking multiple `find`s?

Comment: Similar: [Run find on find](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/560739)

Comment: try to use execdir to run find in find (find -type d ... -execdir find -type f ... -exec)